# How to use query in Google spreadsheet to select column instead of row?

Tags: google-sheets

Please, need your help !!!

I tried

```
=query(A1:E6, "select * where D = 'Yes'", 0)
```

it will select the rows which in column D that has value 'Yes'.

My question is: how to  select the columns which in row 2 that has value 'Yes'. I tried:

```
=query(A1:E6, "select * where 2 = 'Yes'", 0)
```

but it does not work :(

Comment: Column Column1 Column2 Column3 Column5
1 12 3 8 35
2 2 34 5 2
3 232 34 6 5
4 34 34 99 6
5 534 34 10 88

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this with `QUERY`, you would need to do a double `TRANSPOSE`, or use an alternative like `FILTER`.

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:E6),"select * where Col2 = 'Yes'",0))`

or

`=FILTER(A1:E6,A2:E2="Yes")`

Comment: I'm wondering if this can be adapted somehow to deal with when you want to [select one column or another on a per row basis based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639784/filtering-two-columns-into-one-picking-one-or-the-other-according-to-some-condit).

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be so simple, and we can use google query SQL features too:

**Excel Table:**

```
     A       B
1    Qty   | 200
2    Stock | QUESS
3    Start | 8/24/2019
4    End   | 8/23/2020
5    Today | 8/23/2021
```

**Formula:**

```
=query(Transpose(Sheet6!A1:B5),"select *" )
```

**Output :**

```
Qty | Stock | Start     | End       | Today
200 | QUESS | 8/24/2019 | 8/23/2020 | 8/23/2021
```

Note : A similar discussion here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044551/google-sheets-transpose-query/68901704#68901704]