# filtering two columns into one picking one or the other according to some condition

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a filter in Google Sheets which will pick the value from one of two columns, depending on the value of another column in the row.  I have found several questions which seem to ask a similar thing, but I'm not following how to extend the idea to do this.

The test sheet below shows what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

The left half shows the input data, and the right half (starting a column G) shows what I am trying to accomplish.

I am filtering on H1.  I want every row that contains the value of H1 in either column B or column C.  If it appears in Column B, then I also want the value of the corresponding D cell, whereas if it appears in Column C I want the value of the corresponding E cell.  We can assume it will never appear in both column B and C.

I am able to create the G3:I range with this formula in G3:

```
=FILTER(A2:C,(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1))
```

But I'm struggling with the formula to put in J3.

I tried the following formula but it just shows `#VALUE!`:

```
=FILTER({D2:D,E2:E},{(B2:B = H1),(C2:C = H1)})
```

My thinking was that `D2:D, E2:E` would stack up the two columns side by side, and I would use the first one if the B cell matched H1, and the second one if the C cell matched H1.

I tried this formula:

```
=FILTER({D2:D,E2:E},{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})
```

But it shows both columns and I only want one or the other depending on which column the value in H1 shows up in for the row.

I also tried QUERY but they all seem to have syntax errors:

```
=QUERY({D2:D,E2:E},"SELECT (D*(B=H1))",0)
=QUERY({D2:D,E2:E},"SELECT (D*IF(B=H1,1,0))",0)
```

In this case I'm first trying to build up the value by multiplying each column (D and E) by either 1 or 0 depending on whether that's the column I want to look at, and them summing the two.  Since I only have numbers it seems like this approach could work.

It occurred to me that I might use a where clause to only get rows matching one or the other:

```
=QUERY({B2:E},"SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1='"&H1&"'",0)
```

But this only gets rows where B matches H1, and I'm not sure how to combine it with rows where C matches H1 and still keep everything in the correct order.

If I match on either column B or C matching, I still don't know how to select Col3 in one case, and Col4 in the other.  This only gets Col3, which is not correct for #=4:

```
=QUERY({B2:E},"SELECT Col3 WHERE Col1='"&H1&"' OR Col2='"&H1&"'",0)
```

Also, it looks like QUERY may require all data to reside in the current sheet.  In my final version I need to get the data for another sheet, so it looks like trying to use QUERY is out.

Update:
I can create three separate formulas:

```
J3: =FILTER({D2:D,E2:E},{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})
L3: =FILTER(IF(B2:B=H1,1,0),{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})
M3: =FILTER(IF(C2:C=H1,1,0),{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})
```

The sheet then looks like this:
[image]

Is there some way I could combine these into one formula in J3 according to:

```
J3*L3 + K3*M3
```

Comment: why not use a simple if?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do this trick:

```
=FILTER(IF(B2:B=H1,D2:D,E2:E),{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})
```

The second parameter to the filter makes sure that the rows which are selected are the ones in which either the C or D column match the selected value.

The first parameter then picks which is returned.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want is to find the number of the column D if the fruit is the column H or the column E if the fruit is in I.

I started with a simple if, but since H3:H=H1 only returns false once, I had to add an array formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H3:H=H1;/* get the D value */;/* get the E value */))
```

Now I just used your formulas to get the D and E value

```
FILTER(D2:D;{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})
FILTER(E2:E;{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})
```

I got an error for all the empty lines once I putted them all together so I added an `IFERROR`

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H3:H=H1;FILTER(D2:D;{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)});FILTER(E2:E;{(B2:B = H1)+(C2:C = H1)})));"")
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used your suggestion to find a simplified call that uses just one `FILTER` and one `IF` call.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't make it work with the if inside the filter, glad you could work it out!