# Google Sheets - Transpose & Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, transpose

We have a relatively large data set, with roughly 26K rows and 24 columns in the "current format" below.  However, we are trying to reformat it to the desired format below.  I think we may need but Transpose and Query to achieve this but we are open to any method of reaching it.

Any suggestions on how to reformat this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAK, that is a lot of data to process. And it is always difficult to try to write formulas without access to the actual sheet and data. That said, SPLIT/JOIN combos would exceed character limits with that much data. But in theory, the following formula would work (assuming your actual data is an extension of your example and runs from A1:Y.

```
=ArrayFormula({"ID","Value","Qty"; QUERY({VLOOKUP(MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(A1:Y1),1)-1,COUNTA(A:A))+2,{ROW(A:A),A:A},2),HLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(A1:Y1),1)/COUNTA(A:A))+1,{COLUMN(A1:Y1);A1:Y1},2),
VLOOKUP(MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(A1:Y1),1,2)-2,COUNTA(A:A))+2,{ROW(A2:A),B2:Y},ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(A1:Y1),1)/COUNTA(A:A))+1)
},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1 Asc")})
```

If you're wanting to set this up in a separate sheet, you'll need to edit every range throughout the formula to include the name of the sheet where the original data resides.

For more on the basis and explanation for this formula: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/unpivot-in-google-sheets

Comment: Erik, you are right about actual data so sorry for not providing it all.  Thought it might be too much for the example.  Your formula looks great and thank you very much for the link to ben collins example as it looks exactly what we are trying to do.  I'm going to try this tomorrow with fresh eyes.  Never thought it might be called unpivot.

Comment: JAK, I just noticed that parts of the formula I wrote above were written to your example, not your A:Y data. I edited the original formula to accommodate an A:Y range. So you may want to try it again as now written.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"ID", "Value", "Qty"; 
 IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:D="",,A3:A&"♦"&B2:D2&"♦"&B3:D)), "♦"))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Nice, player0. Yet another use for the unofficial FLATTEN. Let's hope Google keeps it around. I find new uses for it daily.

Comment: this is a really interesting formula and it seems to be working great.  I'll spot check our data against the reformatted version.  Quick question what is the purpose of the diamond in the formula?  Flatten seems great by the way.

Comment: diamond is unique character that is used by split to cut the string into cells so in the process it gets nullified. you can instead use any unique symbol you wish ♥☺☻♫♀♂♠♣...

Comment: Another follow up the formula.  The source data a lot zero values in ValueA,ValueB and ValueC.  How might we only reformat when the cell is > 0?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sorry missed this yesterday.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QdQIYBw_eSCRUkYm7_2HqTpypaq2cr6p8wvcv5bYdck/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see your sheet... `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({"DongleId", "Player", "Qty"; IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(Sheet1!E2:AA="",,Sheet1!B2:B&"♦"&Sheet1!E1:AA1&"♦"&Sheet1!E2:AA)), "♦"))}, "where Col3 > 0", 1))`

Comment: That is an enormous help.  Thank so very much, it eliminate over 100K rows we don't need.

Comment: @player0 What to do in the reverse situation? For example how to get this result: https://paste.c-net.org/VotedGymnast from this input: https://paste.c-net.org/MeaslyDisarray

Answer (score 0):

You could try to download the sheet in .csv and make a program to read the data and do the necessary changes, not sure if you're familiar with programming... There are several languages that could be used to achieve that, i have already done something like that in C. Its not very hard.
You could open the file, read the data, process the changes and save in another .csv. Just remember that csv files are just a .txt file separated with commas.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

FILE *file;

FILE *file2;

char Linha[100];
char *result;
int i;


file = fopen("YourSheet.csv", "rt");
file2 = fopen("YourNewSheet.csv", "w");

i = 1;
while (!feof(file))


{
// reads a line
  result = fgets(Linha, 100, file); 
  if (result)
  fprintf(file2, "%s", result);
  i++;


}




fclose(file);
  fclose(file2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be so simple, and we can use google query SQL features too:

**Excel Table:**

```
     A       B
1    Qty   | 200
2    Stock | QUESS
3    Start | 8/24/2019
4    End   | 8/23/2020
5    Today | 8/23/2021
```

**Formula:**

```
=query(Transpose(Sheet6!A1:B5),"select *" )
```

**Output :**

```
Qty | Stock | Start     | End       | Today
200 | QUESS | 8/24/2019 | 8/23/2020 | 8/23/2021
```