# Preparing a csv file splitting data in one cell into multiple lines for hundreds of records

Tags: google-sheets, etl

I have a .csv data extract from a system that is setup in the following format, the extract cannot be changed but I am wanting to transform the data before loading it into either a Google Sheet, MS Access DB or into a SQL Server DB. It is likely Google Sheets will be used as a proof of concept with the production element being in an SQL Server DB.

| id | 07/02/2022 | 08/02/2022 | 09/02/2022 | 10/02/2022 | 11/02/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | / \ | / \ | M \ | / \ | / \ |
| 2 | / \ | / \ | M \ | / \ | / \ |
| 3 | I02 I02 | / \ | I02 I02 | U \ | U \ |
| 4 | I01 M | M M | / \ | / \ | / \ |
| 5 | / \ | / \ | / \ | / \ | / \ |

The first mark in each column is the morning mark and the last mark is the PM mark. i.e. for record 3 on the 04/02/2022 the AM mark is U and the PM mark is \

The file will have in excess of 300 lines each week so should produce a final file with around 1500 lines (300 lines x 5 days a week)

Each results cell will always have two values recorded in each cell seperated by a space i.e. /[space]\ or M[space]\ The data will be extracted on a weekly basis with the column headers having dates that link to a day of the week, Monday through Friday.

For data analysis further down the pipeline I need to split the data so I end up with something like the below (replicated for the first two rows of my master data only):

| Primary ID | id | Date | Period | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 07/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 2 | 1 | 07/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 3 | 1 | 08/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 4 | 1 | 08/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 5 | 1 | 09/02/2022 | AM | M |
| 6 | 1 | 09/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 7 | 1 | 10/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 8 | 1 | 10/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 9 | 1 | 11/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 10 | 1 | 11/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 11 | 2 | 07/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 12 | 2 | 07/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 13 | 2 | 08/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 14 | 2 | 08/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 15 | 2 | 09/02/2022 | AM | M |
| 16 | 2 | 09/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 17 | 2 | 10/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 18 | 2 | 10/02/2022 | PM | | |
| 19 | 2 | 11/02/2022 | AM | / |
| 20 | 2 | 11/02/2022 | PM | | |

I've used an array formula using query, split and flatten as explained in this topic to produce the following output  [Google Sheets - Transpose & Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63049950/9606612)

using this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({"Student", "Date","Mark"; IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(Master!A2:T="",,Master!A2:A&"♦"&Master!I1:M1&"♦"&Master!I2:M)), "♦"))}, "where Col1 > 0", 1))
```

| id | Date | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07/02/2022 | /| |
| 1 | 08/02/2022 | /| |
| 1 | 09/02/2022 | M| |

The problem I am having is trying to create the duplicate line for the AM/PM element. It dosetn exist as an element on its own, and can oly be attributed by the location of the text element in a cell (first element AM, second element PM)

Comment: in your data is there a space between "/" and "\" the way there is between "102" and "102"?

Comment: Here is the shared sheet where I (and others) can demonstrate solutions.  Mine will be on a tab called MK.Help.  Your data is on a tab called OP.Data, so feel free to adjust that tab to best represent the real thing.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPHbjCz7OWE7f31_DjQ1mhWOhb-JWlPTsPayWri1DDU/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: Can you provide your formula as a solution below @MattKing so it can be upvoted? It already seems to have solved the OP's issue above.

Comment: @OctaviaSima I would but the OP didn't answer my question about whether there is a space in the "/\" mark similar to all the others.  If so, the solution is very different.  I thought maybe I should wait, no?

Comment: @MattKing the data will always have a space between the two elements, so there will be a space between  "/" and "\" the way there is between "102" and "102"

Comment: @A.Steer ok, then you should change the data in your question, since there is no space in that data.

Comment: @MattKing thats odd, its showing a space for me. I had also put the followign paragraph saying that there are spaces in all results - "Each results cell will always have two values recorded in each cell seperated by a space i.e. /[space]\ or M[space]\ ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a shared sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPHbjCz7OWE7f31_DjQ1mhWOhb-JWlPTsPayWri1DDU/edit#gid=192852689) with a possible solution to your problem.

It uses the SPLIT()/FLATTEN() technique but you need a nested version to make it work with your layout.

Here is the formula in it's entirety, but this sample is an easier place from which to understand it and will stay up indefinitely.  It should not be important to do it all with one formula (including headers) since this is a proof of concept.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(OP.Data!A2:A100&"|"&OP.Data!B1:1&"|")&{"AM|","PM|"}&SPLIT(FLATTEN(OP.Data!B2:100)," ")),"|",0,0)),"where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null"))
```

Comment: Great thanks that works a treat